# Prove that the number of occurences of x in a list that has n position with valor x = n

Tags: coq

```
Fixpoint n_copies (n x : nat) : list nat :=
  match n with
  | 0 => []
  | S n' => x :: n_copies n' x
  end.

Theorem exercise3
  : forall x n, num_occ x (n_copies n x) = n.
Proof.
```

I tried:

```
intros x n. induction n. simpl.
  - congruence.
  - destruct (eq_dec x n).
    + induction e.
    +
```

but i cant think a solution for another "+", and i have this notice:

```
1 goal
x : nat
IHn : num_occ x (n_copies x x) = x
______________________________________(1/1)
num_occ x (n_copies (S x) x) = S x
```

I think that i have to take of the S of both sides, but i don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange that you had to compare `x` and `n`.
In general, they don't live in the same type:

```
From Coq Require Import List.

Section A_dec. 
Variables (A:Type)(A_eq_dec : forall a b:A, {a = b}+{a <> b}).
Goal forall x n, count_occ A_eq_dec (repeat x n) x = n.
induction n. 
(* ... *)
```

But you didn't share your function `num_occ`..., perhaps it's buggy ?
You should compare it with stdlib's `count_occ`.

Please note also that stdlib’s `repeat` and your `n_copies` don’t have the same order of arguments.

Comment: Indeed, it works with the `num_occ`function of your yesterday's post.
But the case analysis is `destruct (Nat.eq_dec x x)` and not `Nat.eq_dec x n`.
Perhaps a copy-paste error?

Answer (score 0):

Here's is a solution (with `A`as the type of elements of the list):

```
Require Import List Arith.
Import ListNotations. 

Section A_decl. 
Variables (A: Type)(eqdec: forall a b:A, {a = b}+{a <> b}).

Fixpoint n_copies (x:A) (n:nat) : list A :=
  match n with
  | 0 => []
  | S n' => x :: n_copies x n'
  end.

Fixpoint num_occ (x : A)(xs : list A) : nat :=
  match xs with
  | [] => 0
  | (y :: ys) => if eqdec x y
               then 1 + num_occ x ys
               else num_occ x ys
  end.

Theorem exercise3
  : forall x n, num_occ x (n_copies x n) = n.
Proof.
  induction n; simpl. 
  - reflexivity. 
  - destruct (eqdec x x) as [e | n0].
   + rewrite IHn; trivial.
   + now destruct n0.
Qed.

End A_decl.
```